# Edit Photoshop Actions: Export specific

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I would like to optimize images for web but in batches. I have set up and use an Action  Action>Awesome Images>Optimized Awesome Images.

The problem lies when I go to a new set of images that I want to optimize and use the Action. 
Action>Bodacious Images>Optimized Awesome Images

Ideally, I would like to use the Batch features and set the destination folder from that dialogue box at the initial stage of setting up the process. If I can't do that, I would like to be able to be prompted to where the newly optimized images should land.

Are there any plugins for this? Is there a way to edit Actions once they are built, specifically add a prompt for the destination.

Answer (score 2):

Simply toggle the menu button within the action from off to on and it will prompt for the destination:

[image]

With this toggle switch on you can tell each file the location to save to as it processes through the batch. If this doesn't work for you since you have numerous ones to export, the droplet suggestion also works well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding exactly what you're going for, but

You should be able to do everything you're asking for with:
**File / Automate / Batch**

Or you could create a Droplet, possibly one for each location you want images saved to:
**File / Automate / Droplet**

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you can't edit actions. You just delete and remake them. Shouldn't be too hard for a simple Save for Web optimization action. When you create the action, keep recording through a full save for web with your custom options, then stop and save the recording. As for save location, when you set up the Batch(File>Automate>Batch), choose your custom action, and set Destination to folder, and don't let it override the save commands.

Comment: Actions can be edited, breakpoints can be added, and even dialogs prompts added as and when you see fit. Both in the Action panel and in script. Easier in the Action panel.